# IntelliJ - Take standard input from a file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need to take standard input from a file in IntelliJ IDEA.

```
$ java BinarySearch tinyW.txt < tinyT.txt
```

'tinyT.txt' is the file which is to be taken as standard input. 'tinyW.txt' is another file which is passed as a command-line argument to the program.

How can this be achieved through IntelliJ?

PS: I am not running this program from the command-line as the class-path variable hasn't been set, and I am using functions from external libraries.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to create a "Run/Debug Configuration" (Menu "Run" -> "Edit Configurations...").

About halfway down in the configuration panel is an entry "Redirect input from" with a checkbox before it. After selecting the checkbox you can select the file "tinyT.txt".

"tinyW.txt" has to be entered into the field "Program arguments"

---

Some time after writing this answer the Run/Debug configuration dialog has change. In 2023 if you want to redirect the input from some file you need to select "Modify Options" and then "Redirect Input"

Comment: So the file 'tinyW.txt' should be located in the same directory where the .class files are present right?

Comment: @KarthikBhat that depends on your application. If your application just does `new FileInputStream(filename)` then the file should be in the project directory.

Comment: I makes sense to tell relative and absolute paths apart here...

Comment: It seems ```Redirect input from``` option has been removed from IntelliJ 2023.1.2

Comment: @Madstuffs it disappeared from the default "Run" dialog layout, but you can still find it when you select "Modify Options"