# How to redirect Kotlin stdio to files?

Tags: redirect, kotlin, stdout, stdin, stdio

Is it possible to redirect **Kotlin** `stdio` to files through command line parameters, something like `< input.txt > output.txt`?
If not, is there any simple way?

I'm using **IntelliJ IDEA**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the program with an IntelliJ IDEA *run configuration*, then you can configure it to save the console output to a file.

1. Open the run configuration settings:

   [image: Open the run configuration settings]
2. In the *Logs* tab, check *Save console output to file* and enter the file name:

   [image]

Redirecting is possible for Java applications as per 
[this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54360790/intellij-take-standard-input-from-a-file), but this option seems to be missing for Kotlin. This is a known issue, please vote and follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28854

Redirecting the input and output with `<` and `>` is the shell feature, and passing these arguments to the JVM or your program won't make any effect.